# Object comparison

Tags: java, object, comparison, boolean

Hello I am trying to write a Java comparison which takes the current object called MovieCard and compares it with another MovieCard passed as a parameter. code below

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {

    if(this.MovieCard.equals(movieCard))


    return true;
}
```

error cannot find symbol - variable MovieCard

The check is listed in my class before the MovieCard constructor if this makes any difference. Also I'm in a beginner programming class so we cannot use Comparator and it needs to contain this.

Comment: are you sure that you wanted `this.MovieCard` and not just `this`?

Comment: Did you declaere the attribute `Moviecard`? Not the parameter passed to the method, but the attribute.

Comment: Thank you everyone who contributed great answers!

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    return this.equals(movieCard);
}
```

Comment: This won't compile either. Remove `MovieCard` after `this`.

Comment: `return this.equals(movieCard);` - as I understand OP's question, `sameName`is a method of `MovieCard`.

Answer (score 1):

`MovieCard` is a class, not a variable. And that's what the compiler is telling you.

```
if(this.MovieCard.equals(movieCard))
        ↑
```

You probably have to write only `this`.

Also note that there exists a path that doesn't return anything, this won't compile.

You should do:

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    return this.equals(movieCard);
}
```

Or

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    if(this.equals(movieCard)) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this method is present in your `MovieCard` class, then just `this` would suffice.

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    if(this.equals(movieCard)) {// this is enough. this.MovieCard is wrong, as there is no variable by that name.
        return true;
    }
    return false; // Since return true is a conditional return, but the method needs to return in any case.
}
```

And a shortened version of your method would be

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    return this.equals(movieCard); // Returns the result of the comparison.
}
```

If looking at the method name, `sameName()`, it looks like you want to compare some name field in the class, instead of the objects as such.

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    return this.getName().equals(movieCard.getName()); // Returns the result of the name comparison.
    // But there is a possible NPE in the above statement.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use like

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
    if(this.equals(movieCard))
       return true;
}
```

But it seems your method is checking whether two object has same name. if so then you can simply use

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {

    if(this.name.equals(movieCard.name))
         return true;
}
```

assuming name is a member variable(string)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

```
boolean sameName(MovieCard movieCard) {
 if (this.equals(movieCard)){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

Because `this.MovieCard`  points to a variable in your `Moviecard` class.

**Besides your syntax error, Your equals implementation does nothing other that default implementation**

Remember   `if (this.equals(movieCard)){`  This is only true when the `movieCard` and `this`  points to the same reference.

**Because,**

Default implementation of `equals()` class provided by **java.lang.Object** compares memory location and only `return` true if two reference variable are pointing to same memory location i.e. essentially they are same object.

I guess you need to override the equals method in your `MovieCard` class, Such that comparing the fields of `MovieCard's` are same or not.

[Prefers to read, How to essentially `Ovveride` equals.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)

You are moving in a wrong direction, Please see the example in the above link and then implement equals
 in such a way that If all the fields in MovieCard `equals` to the passed Object's fields. That would be the implementation you asked for.

In general [an example for comparing two Tiger Object's](http://javapapers.com/core-java/hashcode-and-equals-methods-override/)  for equals like this

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
      result = false;
    } else {
      Tiger tiger = (Tiger) object;
      if (this.color == tiger.getColor() //checking color and pattern same
          && this.stripePattern == tiger.getStripePattern()) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

all the answers given above answers your question so i would like to add this too.

> keep in mind that the `equals` method called belongs to the object method. so it would be wise for you to override the `equals` method to fit the needs of your program. and when you override equals make sure you override the `hashcode` method too..